# Edit / personalize PirateBox's HTML file?

Tags: html, filepath, openwrt, file-sharing, firmware

So I have made a PirateBox, but I wish to make edits to the HTML file - to give more functionality and a new look to the webpage. I am confident that I can edit it - but I can't find it. I have looked online and on this site for answers, to no avail.

An additional inquiry: Do I need to re-flash the router / firmware once I edit the HTML file? This question really isn't too much of a concern at this point, though.

Thanks to all that can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a great guide to personalize the PirateBox - including the HTML file. [Here](https://www.disk91.com/2012/technology/systems/customizing-piratebox-configuration/) is the page.

To quote the page:

> **Change the index.html page**
>
> I don’t really like the index.html page as it does not show the files available, more over the english language is not adapted of every one, so I prefer a frame organization mixing files, local text and chat area.
>
> The index.html file can be changed by replacing it: create a new one and copy it to the following place: `/opt/piratebox/www/index.html`

It also includes a guide to change the SSID and the Chat settings.